# Is this set uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I would like to ask a question that is a little vague; please bear with me.

Consider the following situation: For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define a countable set $A_n=\{a_{0,n},a_{1,n}\dots\}$. For each $A_n$ and for each element $a_{m,n}$ of $A_n$ we define a countable set $A_{m,n} = \{a_{0,m,n},a_{1,m,n}, a_{2,m,n},\dots\}$

...

We continue this process and finally we take the union of all the sets that we have defined. Is this an uncountable set?

**EDIT** I'll write down some of the steps:

1. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define $A_n$ to be a countable set, namely $A_n=\{a_0,a_1,\dots\}$.
2. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for each $a_m\in A_n$ we define the set $A_{m,n}=\{a_{0,m,n} , a_{1,m,n}, a_{2,m,n},\dots\}$
3. For each $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ and for each $a_{k,m,n}\in A_{m,n}$ we define the set $A_{k,m,n}=\{a_{0,k,m,n}, a_{1,k,m,n}, a_{2,k,m,n},\dots\}$

...

...

At time = $\infty$ we take the Union of all these countable sets. *This* is the set I'm talking about. I believe that the family of sets can be enumarated in the same way that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}^n$ can; so what we actually have is a countable union of countable sets, but it is too counter intuitive for me; anyone can confirm/ disprove?

Comment: Do you repeat this operation a countable number of times?

Comment: I am not sure how to reply; I repeat this process for every element of every set that is defined on the current moment I guess. I'm sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited my answer based on reinterpretation of the question; I believe the following is correct to the situation now.

At each step $m$, the sets $A_{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m}$ are countable, so $$\bigcup_{(n_1,\ldots,n_m)\in\Bbb N^m}A_{n_1,\ldots,n_m}$$is a countable union of countable sets, and is therefore countable. We are interested in the union $$\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{(n_1,\ldots,n_m)\in\Bbb N^m}A_{n_1,\ldots,n_m}\right)$$which is a countable union of countable sets, and is therefore countable.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear; we continue this process for every set and each of its elements that has been defined at the current moment; the indexes will keep on going

Comment: So when you have $A_{m,n}$ you choose an element $a_{l,m,n}$ and construct $A_{l,m,n}=\{a_{0,l,m,n},a_{1,l,m,n},\ldots\}$?

Comment: In this case I think what you define is similar to $\mathbb R$ ($ \mathbb N \times \dots \times \mathbb N =\mathbb N ^{\mathbb N }$: all infinite combination of integers) which is not countable

Comment: Yes, you do that for every element of $A_{m,n}$, for every set $A_{m,n}$ and so on

Comment: See my edit, I believe this makes sense now.

Comment: It does make sense I suppose; I was trying to construct an uncountable family of uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and this was equivalent to whether or not my collection was uncountable. Thanks @Dave